# Searching for songs in Spotify iOS API

Tags: ios, spotify

I want to incorporate the ability for a user to search for a Spotify song with keywords. I noticed in CocoaLibSpotify there is a `searchWithSearchQuery:`, but have not seen anything similar in the Spotify API. Using CocoaLibSpotify was discouraged because it is deprecated.

Is there any way to search with the Spotify API?

Answer (score 1):

The Spotify API has a [/v1/search](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/). It takes a **q** parameter, your search query, and a **type** parameter, which is the type of thing to search (in the case of songs, that's "track"). So you could hit **/v1/search?type=track&q=** to search for a song.

Comment: Can i use spotify to share music and full playback within my own app. I want user to share music with search bar and share instantly without user login into spotify. Just random tracks search by users and play within app?
Use case https://developer.spotify.com/use-cases/mobile-apps/messaging/
https://developer.spotify.com/use-cases/mobile-apps/messaging/